# What's the relationship between input power and intensity / frequency of radiated EM waves?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, soft-question

I've seen an example of an electric dipole that radiates power proportional to $\ \omega^{4} $.

My question is: given a fixed amount of input power to drive the dipole, while varying the driving frequency, is the "intensity" of a lower frequency radiated wave greater than than the "intensity" of a higher frequency radiated wave ?

A related question is : what is generally the measure of "intensity" for EM waves, perhaps something akin to Gauss' Law for electrostatics ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intensity that you talk about can be represented bt the Poynting vector. 
$$ {\bf N} = {\bf E} \times {\bf H}$$
The units are Watts per square metre.

The power produced by an oscillating electric dipole can be derived by integrating an expression for the Poynting vector over a surface area enclosing the dipole.
$$ P = \oint {\bf N} \cdot d{\bf S}.$$

The EM waves from the dipole have perpendicular electric and magnetic fields, the amplitudes of which depend on $1/r$. The frequency dependence is given either by $I_0 \omega$, if the dipole is driven by a current of amplitude $I_0$, or $p_0 \omega^2$ if you think of it as moving charge in an electric dipole of amplitude $p_0$ (recall that $I = dQ/dt$). This leads to a Poynting vector and a total power that depends on either $I_{0}^{2}\omega^2$ or $p_{0}^{2}\omega^4$ respectively.

So, for a given radiated power, the Poynting vector (your "intensity") is fixed. But if you increase the frequency then to produce the same Poynting vector you would need a lower current amplitude in the dipole. For a finite resistance this would lead to lower resistive losses. So your "input power" has to be divided between the resistive losses and the amount of radiation power produced. For a fixed input power, more goes into radiation if you increase the frequency. Of course, if you increase the frequency too much then your electric dipole approximation, that $\omega \ll l/c$, might be compromised.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I think there may be a small contradiction. If there are more resistive losses at a lower frequency how can the radiated power (surface integral of the Poynting vector - which you say is fixed given input power) for both frequencies be the same ?

Comment: Ah ok. The surface integral of the Poynting vector gives total power produced by dipole not just radiated power. Some of this is lost to resistive elements.

Comment: So given input power, higher frequency EM waves radiated are more energetic/powerful than lower frequency ones primarily due to resistive losses at lower frequency ?

Comment: Poynting vector is independent of frequency. I should have said, for a given *radiated* power, the Poynting vector is constant.